# I would like to know how to keep an inventory variable in a class the same for all new objects?

Tags: php, oop

The problem am having is keeping my inventory variable keep up with the changes made by different objects. For example, the $me object buys 4 items, which deducts from the inventory and leaves 6 in the inventory that is good. Then I make a new object $l, but the inventory starts from 10 again, instead of the new current inventory of 6.

Below is my PHP code for my class

```
class cashRegister {
    public $total = 0;
    public $name;
    public $discount;
    public $lastamount;
    public $inventory = 10;
    public function __construct($name, $discount) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
    public function add($itemCost) {
        $this->total += $itemCost;
        $this->lastamount = $itemCost;
    }
    public function scan($item, $quantity) {
        switch ($item) {
            case "eggs" :
                $this->add ( 1 * $quantity);
                $this->inventory($quantity);
                break;
            case "news" :
                $this->add(2 * $quantity);
                $this->inventory($quantity);
        }
        //$this->inventory -= $quantity;
    }
    public function inventory($quantity) {
        $this->inventory -= $quantity;
    }
    public function staffDiscount() {
        $this->total -= ($this->total * ($this->discount/100)) ;
    }
    public function voidL() {
        $this->total -= $this->lastamount;
    }
}
```

Below is my normal code

```
include 'cashRegister.php';
$me = new cashRegister("Mg", 20);
$l = new cashRegister("ll", 50);
echo $me->inventory;
$me->scan("eggs", 2);
$me->scan("eggs", 1);
$me->scan("news", 1);
//$me->staffDiscount();
echo $me->inventory;
//echo $l->inventory;
//echo $me->total;
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a more extended OOP example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new instance of a class (that happens whenever you use the keyword `new`) it will create a brand new kind of 'copy' or 'instance' of that class.  So, when you subtract the inventory amount, you are only subtracting from that instance.

PHP has the keyword `static` that will change the public instance variable of $inventory into a kind of shared variable between all instances of that class.

Update it from public to static to look like this:

```
public static $inventory = 10;
```

But you also need several other changes because you cannot reference a static variable in the same way as an instance variable.

Basically you need to change `$this->` to `self::` in your inventory method:

```
public function inventory($quantity) {
    self::$inventory -= $quantity;
}
```

Then when you reference the static variable from the instance variable you need to access it like this:

```
echo $me::$inventory;
```

Your final code would look like this:

```
<?
class cashRegister {
    public $total = 0;
    public $name;
    public $discount;
    public $lastamount;
    public static $inventory = 10;
    public function __construct($name, $discount) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
    public function add($itemCost) {
        $this->total += $itemCost;
        $this->lastamount = $itemCost;
    }
    public function scan($item, $quantity) {
        switch ($item) {
            case "eggs" :
                $this->add ( 1 * $quantity);
                $this->inventory($quantity);
                break;
            case "news" :
                $this->add(2 * $quantity);
                $this->inventory($quantity);
        }
        //$this->inventory -= $quantity;
    }
    public function inventory($quantity) {
        self::$inventory -= $quantity;
    }
    public function staffDiscount() {
        $this->total -= ($this->total * ($this->discount/100)) ;
    }
    public function voidL() {
        $this->total -= $this->lastamount;
    }
}
```

And when you call it:

```
$me = new cashRegister("Mg", 20);
$l = new cashRegister("ll", 50);
echo $me::$inventory;
echo "<br>";
$me->scan("eggs", 2);
$me->scan("eggs", 1);
$me->scan("news", 1);
//$me->staffDiscount();
echo $me::$inventory;
//echo $l->inventory;
//echo $me->total;
```

---

Here is an updated class that gives you a more extended idea of how you can use objects.
Instead of just an inventory class, it breaks down an item into an individual class and object that you can use.

When an item is scanned it loops through the inventory items and if there is not enough of that item in stock it will return false - in a real world scenario, you would probably handle that error differently but for this case it is okay.  You might add a method called 'isItemInStock()' to the Inventory class that will check if it is available first.

So now that the inventory is an object its instance is shared between the other objects as well as the items that are in stock.  Instead of adding/subtracting the totals during the scan process there is a getTotal() method that will recalculate the total with the discount.

```
<?

class Item {

    public $name;
    public $cost;
    public $quantity;

    public function __construct($name, $cost, $quantity=null) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->cost = $cost;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }
}


class Inventory
{
    public $items = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function add($item) {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }
}

class CashRegister {

    public $name;
    public $discount;
    public $inventory;

    public $items = array();

    public function __construct($name, $discount, $inventory) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->discount = $discount;
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
    }

    public function add($item) {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function scan( $name, $qty ) {
        foreach ($this->inventory->items as $key => $item) {
            if ($item->name==$name) {
                if (($item->quantity-$qty)>=0) {
                    $this->inventory->items[$key]->quantity -= $qty;
                    $this->add( new Item($item->name, $item->cost, $qty) );
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not added, not enough
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Invalid item
        return false;
    }

    public function getTotal() {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($this->items as $item) {
            $total += $item->cost*$item->quantity;
        }
        $discount = ((100-$this->discount)/100);
        echo "Discount total: $discount\n";
        return $total - $discount;
    }
}

$inventory = new Inventory();
$inventory->add( new Item('eggs', 1, 20) );
$inventory->add( new Item('news', 2, 50) );

$cb1 = new CashRegister(1, 20, $inventory );

echo "<pre>\n";
echo "Scanning 5 eggs\n";
$cb1->scan( 'eggs', 5);

foreach ($inventory->items as $item) {
    echo $item->name . ': '. $item->quantity." in stock\n";
}

echo "Scanning 6 news\n";
$cb1->scan( 'news', 5);

foreach ($inventory->items as $item) {
    echo $item->name . ': '. $item->quantity." in stock\n";
}

$cb2 = new CashRegister(2, 30, $inventory );
echo "Scanning 3 eggs\n";
$cb2->scan('eggs', 3);

foreach ($inventory->items as $item) {
    echo $item->name . ': '. $item->quantity." in stock\n";
}

echo "Cash Register 1 Total: " . $cb1->getTotal() . "\n";
echo "Cash Register 2 Total: " . $cb2->getTotal() . "\n";
```

Comment: This is the same change that I had suggested (that you need a static attribute), but @ChrisBanks did a great job of writing up the additional changes you need and why the changes were necessary.  I removed my answer as this one does a better job of explaining it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, and Chris. One question is their a way to reply back to comments or do you just leave a comment?

Comment: If you leave a comment we are both notified.  You can mention a specific person using the `@` followed by typing their name (it will auto suggest the names of users).

Comment: Change it from `public $items = [];` to `public $items = array();` in the Inventory and CashRegister class.  Newer versions of PHP allow the shorter syntax `[]` but older versions only allow `array()` -- which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: In general, PHP 5.6, or above is recommended.  Are you running PHP off your computer? OSX? Windows?

Comment: Take a look here to see which versions of PHP are being currently supported - http://php.net/supported-versions.php -- you can use an old version if you really need to but really you should upgrade.  If you are on OSX I recommend installing Brew (www.brew.sh) then install php from the command line, or on Windows install XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

I would define your inventory separately and add it to your cash register invocation.

```
class Inventory
{
    public $eggs;
    public $news;

    public function __construct($eggs = 10, $news = 10)
    {
        $this->eggs = $eggs;
        $this->news = $news;
    }
}
```

You would need to modify your CashRegister class to use the properties of the object rather than just modifying the inventory property, and accept the inventory as an argument.

```
class CashRegister
{
    // ...
    protected $inventory;

    public function __construct($inventory, name, $discount)
    {
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }

    // ...

    public function scan($item, $quantity)
    {
        switch ($item) {
            case "eggs" :
                $this->add ( 1 * $quantity);
                $this->inventory($item, $quantity);
                break;
            case "news" :
                $this->add(2 * $quantity);
                $this->inventory($item, $quantity);
        }
    }

    protected function inventory($item, $quantity)
    {
        $this->inventory->$item -= $quantity;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$inventory = new Inventory;
$me = new CashRegister($inventory, 'mg', 20);
$l = new CashRegister($inventory, 'l', 50);
// ...
```

Because objects are always passed by reference, your inventory object is now in sync between both registers, and the changes made in either will affect the available inventory.

Comment: Hello Solocommand, your way of doing it is really cool. I tried to implement it but I got a "Fatal error: Class 'Inventory' not found" even though I included it the file.

Comment: Glad you like it! Passing objects to other objects is the basis of how dependency injection works in PHP and it's a great practice to learn and implement. Regarding the class not found: try adding the inventory class definition in your CashRegister.php file, either above or below the other class. PSR states that there should only be one class per file, but if you aren't using an auto loader it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: Thanks so much solo command, the code works perfectly and now it has the added ability to keep track of what items are being bought, instead of the vague "inventory" descriptor.  Am currently making this program to learn more about php oop, do you have any good resources to look at?